# Topologically Transitive Flow on $R^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-dynamics

I have been looking but cannot find the following: an example of a topologically transitive map on $\mathbb{S}^n$ or on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for arbitrary $n$).  Here, by a topologically transitive flow, I mean a smooth map
$$
\begin{aligned}
f:[0,1]\times \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n
\end{aligned}
$$
such that $\{f(t,x):t \in [0,1]\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{S}^n$ for some $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the paper

[V. López and G. López, *Transitive flows on manifolds*, Rev. Mat. Iberoam.
**20** (2004), 107-130](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1080928422)

for the general solution.

Comment: I'm not sure it gives anything explicit for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (unless I overlooked something...)

Comment: You did, but that's ok.